# Issue with Automatic Time Zone Detection and Location Services on Mac Mini M2 Pro

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, geolocation

Hello StackExchange Community,

I recently acquired a Mac Mini with the M2 Pro chip and have encountered a perplexing issue that I hope someone here might have experienced and resolved, or could provide some insights into. Despite my extensive background in system/DevOps roles within the software industry and familiarity with troubleshooting, this problem has left me baffled.

### Issue Description

- **Automatic Time Zone Detection:** From the moment I powered on the device, the automatic time zone detection feature, which should ideally adjust based on my location, consistently defaults to Cupertino's time zone. This occurs regardless of manual adjustments or system resets.
- **Maps App:** The app fails to pinpoint my exact location, rendering it incapable of providing accurate directions or focusing on my current position.
- **Safari Location Services:** When using location services on websites, including Apple and Google Maps, the system is unable to accurately identify my location.

### Troubleshooting Steps Taken

1. Confirmed that location services are enabled system-wide, including on Safari and Find My Mac.
2. Verified that no VPNs were active, and the issue has persisted from the initial setup.
3. Attempted to connect via both LAN and multiple Wi-Fi networks, observing that other Apple devices on the same networks do not exhibit this issue.
4. Restarted my router several times and renewed the DHCP lease.
5. Performed a complete data wipe and reinstalled macOS, which unfortunately did not resolve the issue.

I have thoroughly searched through search engines and Apple support forums, double-checking all possible settings and configurations related to this problem, but to no avail.

### Seeking Suggestions

Given the troubleshooting steps I've already undertaken, I am seeking insights into:

- How the Mac Mini determines its precise location (I assume through the IP address)?
- Any advanced troubleshooting steps I might not have considered?
- Specific diagnostics I can run to gain more clarity on the malfunction?

I appreciate your time and any advice you can offer. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: My first thought was the machine may be enrolled in some type of MDM (Jamf, Addigy, Mosyle etc). Check System Settings > Privacy > Profiles and see if anything is listed there.

Comment: Alternatively, the `profiles -[PCLe]` commands could be helpful, run both with & without sudo.

Comment: @luckman212 thanks but I tried both, no profiles detected and "Client is not DEP enabled".

Comment: Which timezone and closest city is set in the "Date & Time" settings? If this a newly bought Mac, you could also reach out directly to Apple Support (or just bring it to a Store/return it).

Comment: @nohillside It's Cupertino, the default one.

Comment: Ah, and you already mentioned that manual changes don't stick. As said before, if this happens even after a complete reinstall, I would bring it back to Apple.